# Tagging people from facebook like/share button on webpage

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to tag people when "liking/sharing" a page from a facebook like button on a webpage?  I've tried looking through their API docs, but I only found to put an `@` infront of their name, but this still doesn't work.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible.